# HTML5 and CSS - Responsive Video Pop Up Not working according to design

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video, portfolio

I am building an online portfolio and am running into an issue with the video popup.

What happens now is that when you click on it, it loads everything as a new page.  Then it opens a small video followed by immediately popping it full screen.  You have to press back to go back to the portfolio page.  And once there, the full screen video (usually) hovers whenever you are near the picture you launched it from.

Essentially I need to have a photo/text that acts as a button.  You click on it and it pops open a floating responsive video on the same page.  You click on the close or anywhere else and it goes away and you're still on the same page.

Here's an active link to the test portfolio page in question.  Lots of dead links in there - just reference the 1st Aquaman image. https://www.marksantora.com/portfolio_test/portfolio_test.html

Thanks for any help!

***Here's the HTML Code for the image/pop up:***

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 items theatrical social">
 <div class="item mt-40">
  <div class="img">
   <img src="assets/imgs/website_new/portfolio_img/aquaman_and_the_lost_kingom_01p.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="cont d-flex align-items-center">

    <div id="light">
      <a class="boxclose" id="boxclose" onclick="lightbox_close();"></a>
      <video id="Aquamanandthelostkingdom" controls> <source src="https://www.marksantora.com/H264/aquaman2_BloodIsThickerThanWater.mp4">
      </video>
    </div>

    <div id="fade" onClick="lightbox_close();"></div>
                    
        <div>
     <h5 class="fz-22">
      <a href="https://www.marksantora.com/H264/aquaman2_BloodIsThickerThanWater.mp4" onclick="lightbox_open();">Aquaman and the Lost Kingdom</a>
     </h5>
     <p>
      <a href="https://www.marksantora.com/H264/aquaman2_BloodIsThickerThanWater.mp4" onclick="lightbox_open();">Blood Is Thicker Than Water</a>
      </p>
    </div>                              

        <div class="ml-auto">
         <a href="https://www.marksantora.com/H264/aquaman2_BloodIsThickerThanWater.mp4" class="ti-arrow-top-right"></a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

***And the CSS:***

```
/* HTML 5 Video playing in a lightbox
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/

#fade {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1001;
  -moz-opacity: 0.8;
  opacity: .80;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

#light {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  max-width: auto;
  max-height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  background: #FFF;
  z-index: 10000;
  overflow: visible;
}

#boxclose {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #222222;
  font-size: 31px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding: 11px 3px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  z-index: 1002;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.boxclose:before {
  content: "×";
}

#fade:hover ~ #boxclose {
  display:none;
}

.test:hover ~ .test2 {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues that you need to address.
The first issue is that you must stop the browser from navigating to the video URL specified in `a href`.

To achieve this, you need to return `false` from your `onclick` handler, like so:

```
<a href="../H264/aquaman2_BloodIsThickerThanWater.mp4"
  onclick="return lightbox_open()">Aquaman and the Lost Kingdom</a>
```

and then

```
function lightbox_open() {
  ...
  return false;
}
```

Another major problem is that your `lightbox_open` references an element with an id that doesn't exist, i.e. `VisaChipCardVideo`

I guess (from your `lightbox_close`) that it must be `Aquamanandthelostkingdom`, like so:

```
function lightbox_open() {
  var lightBoxVideo = document.getElementById("Aquamanandthelostkingdom");
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  document.getElementById("light").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("fade").style.display = "block";
  lightBoxVideo.play();
  return false;
}
```

After fixing these two problems, the browser will not navigate to the video URL, and your lightbox will show up.

The next step would be to properly implement lightbox behavior to look and behave like a modal popup, preventing the user from interacting with the website while the lightbox is visible.

You can look at this example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp or use some popular lightbox JS components.

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this.  Your help on the code fixed the mp4 opening in another page.

Now after clicking the text in the image, the mp4 opens very large on the current page but is in the descriptor box.  Additionally the video is behind the other images on the page.

I have updated the link from above with the new code:  https://www.marksantora.com/portfolio_test/portfolio_test.html

Thoughts?

Comment: I answered your original question and gave you hints on what to look into to progress further.  The concept of StackOverflow is to unblock a developer by answering a specific question. However, proper implementation of lightbox (in fact, modal popup) is a much broader topic than a single question.  Try to open the link that I've mentioned, and you should be able to implement the same logic. Feel free to ask new questions (not in the scope of this question) if you have any during your further progress. Learning is a bit painful process, but it always pays off.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it was helpful and resolved the blocker you mentioned in the question. See you in the new questions. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I do appreciate it.  I've have read up on the Modal implementation and am working to implement it.